# Doesn't catch submit from connected js, where to dig?

Tags: javascript

Task: To catch the form triggering on the page.
There is the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e){
          alert('wtf?');
     })
})
```

In externally connected js there is a code of the following content, triggered by a click on a certain element:

```
h.redirect = function (a, b) {
        var c = k.createElement("form");
        c.action = b;
        c.method = "post";
        c.target = "_top";
        c.style.display = "none";
        var d = k.createElement("input");
        d.type = "hidden";
        d.name = "token";
        d.value = a;
        c.appendChild(d);
        k.body.appendChild(c);
        c.submit()
    }
```

Attention question: With c.submit () nothing is caught, the coconut does not grow, the alert does not come out, but the form works and the submit occurs. How to catch an event, or at least explain why such crap? Doesn't c.submit () create a event?

UPD: Thank you all, I am a stupid elk, I did not look at the code properly, or where the callback is described without a submission.

Comment: Why are you adding `on('submit')` to your document, instead of to your form element? Also, never use `alert`, which can _only_ log strings in a thread-blocking dialog popup. Use `console.log()`, which can log _literally anything_ in a nicely explorable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not very cool that a third-party script allows itself such freedoms such as directly invoking submit, or how specific it can be. This approach leaves no choice but to decorate:

```
(() => {
    var old_submit = HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit;

    HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit = function() {
        var form = this,
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
            submit_event = new Event('submit', {
                bubbles: true,
                cancelable: true
            });

        submit_event.original_submit = function() {
            old_submit.apply(form, args);
        };

        form.dispatchEvent(submit_event);
    }
})();

$(() => {
    var my_form = $( 'form' )[0];

    $( document )
        .on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
            alert('wtf?');
            e.originalEvent.original_submit();
        })
        .on('click', 'button', function() {
            my_form.submit();
        });
})
```

The point is to call out the object of the event when invoking the submission, in which there is a link to the original submit, which is the only way to send the form. This is horror, nightmare and hell, and I would never do that, but I didn’t think of anything better.